# How to use ngFor trackBy but notify about component input change?

Tags: angular, ngfor

```html
<div *ngFor="let obj of objs; trackby:objToId">
  <sample-component [obj]="obj"></sample-component>
</div>
```

**Actual behaiviour :**

- `sample-component` is not notifed about changes in obj attributes.

**Desired behaiviour :**

- `sample-component` should be notifed about any obj attribute change without rerendering component.

How to achieve desired behaiviour ?

Comment: try to remove trackBy

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi if I remove it the whole component will be reinitialized and this will reset form inputs inside it. I want it only to be notified about input changes but not rerendered.

Comment: How are you changing the data? Are you mutating the objects, or overwriting them? So: `objs[n].someProperty = newValue`, or `objs[n] = someNewObject`?

Comment: @mbojko I am mutating objects since objs are comming from ngxs state.

Answer (score 0):

If you're mutating some property of `obj`, Angular's change detection won't notice that (doing shallow comparison), `trackBy` is not guilty here.

Try overwriting the entire `obj`, so the object reference changes. So, for example, instead of

```
objs[n].someProperty = newValue;
```

do

```
objs[n] = Object.assign({}, objs[n], { someProperty: newValue });
```

Comment: I am mutating the whole object as described but this doesn't solve the problem, ngFor does not notify sample-component about input change.

Comment: Could you please provide the code that does the changing?

Comment: if you change `obj.prop = X` it won't do. what you should be doing is `obj = { ...obj, prop : 'X'}`

Comment: @mbojko code that does the change is an action dispatch using ngxs. objs are results of state selector subscriptions

Comment: @Stavm even what you suggest doesn't solve the problem since trackBy check only ids, if they are the same it consider there is no reason to notify sample-component which is strange behaiviour of trackBy

Comment: You can test your theory on tracking by having only one component: remove the loop and just have `<sample-component [obj]="objs[0]" />`. Does it notice the change?

Comment: @mbojko yes it notice the change, the problem comes only when using ngFor & trackBy